# Drag and drop some elements lagging

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I'm trying to make a script using Jquery UI (droppable and draggable).
Link: http://temp.spendhunters.ru/4.php

There are 4 white icons around the yellow icon. White will have to drop on the yellow. With those icons on the left - everything is fine. The problem with those on the right, they lag behind when you drag the cursor, and the event "Drop" does not work.

How can i fix it?
I want all white icons to drop on yellow without errors and with normal animation.

Comment: For the future, please don't start a question with `Some error` !

Comment: Can you post a fiddle please?

Comment: Show some code... (for example in http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `right:0` from the right positioned div. Replace it with `left:100%` or any numeric value for `left` which suits your design. The delay is due to the `right:0` css in the right positioned div. Try it, it should solve your issue. You can try this change in browser console itself.

Comment: +1 Nice answer.  Any ideas as to *why* this happens?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker Thanks, but I am not too sure about this issue. It happened with me in one of my project. I tried finding for the reason then but couldn't find any concrete answers.